# What is the significance of "sums to 10" in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), Hank and his daughter Hope learn that Janet has been using Scott as her antenna:

> Hank: I'm tracking your signal using subatomic frequencies... between
>   point two and point nine.
>
> Scott (as Janet): I'd narrow it to **four and six**.
>
> Hank: That's too tight. We could miss you.
>
> Scott (as Janet): Look at us squabbling again.
>
> Hank: Fine. All right, between **three and seven**.

What is the significance of "sums to 10" in this scene?

Comment: 2 + 9 = 11, not 10, so I don’t think there is any significance. Basically, after the first, the rest are two numbers equidistant from 0.5 which will always sum to 10.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod that is the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## There is none.

They're just discussing intervals, some more narrow than others. Hank suggests [0.2, 0.9], and Scott suggests something smaller, [0.4, 0.6]. Since Hank thinks that's too narrow, they compromise on [0.3, 0.7]. The intervals are approximately centered around 0.5 and equidistant from there.